# Application can't change DNS to IP on SQL Server connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, dns, connection

I have a weird issue in C#.

I have SQL Server database hosted remotely.

My C# application is connecting to this database using DNS name as Server name. 
Let's say: "myremoteserver.com". I use connection string etc. If I run my app from Visual Studio it's working correctly. Connection is made, can do what I want with it.

Problem starts when I try to run my application directly from compiled exe outside Visual Studio (no matter if from debug or release folder). It says that host is unknown. I try then to change server name to IP address of this DNS name and then its working like a charm.

Why does Visual Studio know how to translate DNS name to IP and compiled app doesn't?

I have database on dynamic IP hosting so I need to use no-ip adress, can't use IP.

Any ideas why in compiled version it can't translate DNS?

Comment: sounds like a .config file issue.. so what .config file are you using in the folder when you run the .exe outside of VS also do you use a HOST file..?

Comment: Yes I use txt file as config and its loading correctly. I made hard-coded MessageBox that display connectionstring just before connecting and it is the same as when I run app from VS. 

In fact in VS I run app in debug mode and it loads the same config file as if I run app from exe in the same debug folder. It seems while connecting VS knows how to change DNS name to IP address somehow.

Comment: are you deploying from the release folder and if so are the config or text file settings the same..